# How to start a new activity which has no parent?

Tags: android, android-activity, new-operator, back

In my android studio project I am starting new activity from main activity.

```
public void authenticated() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthenticatedActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I am pressing back button in main activity, the application exits to desktop. But when I am starting new activity with function `authenticated()` and pressing back button, the application goes back to main activity. I want it to exit to desktop instead of going back to main activity. How can I organize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to close the current activity when you are opening a new one call the `finish()`.

**Example**

```java
public void authenticated() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthenticatedActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Also you can add `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` to clean the activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(isTaskRoot()){
            authenticated()
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `moveTaskToBack(true)` on onBackPressed of your AuthenticatedActivity as shown below

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true);
 }
```